# example-based f-score is smaller than precision and recall in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing multi-label classification and the evaluation is done by `precision_recall_fscore_support` with `average = 'samples'`:

```
predict = array(([1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,1]))
expect = array(([1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,0], [1,0,0,0]))
smp_report = precision_recall_fscore_support(expect, predict, average = 'samples')
f_report = f1_score(expect, predict, average = 'samples')
```

There are three instances in this examples and the binary value stand for the existence of corresponding four classes.

then `smp_report` and `f_report` give me `(0.58333333333333337, 0.61111111111111105, 0.48888888888888893, None)` and `0.488888888889` respectively.

The f-score is not equal to the result of `2*smp_report[0]*smp_report[1]/(smp_report[0]+smp_report[1])` which is the harmonic mean of precision and recall.

Could anyone tell me how does Sklearn implement this one? The version I am using is 0.15.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scikit-learn first calculates the precision, recall, and harmonic F-measure for each item in your set of lists (`[1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,1]`). It then calculates the mean of those precision values, the mean of those recall values, and the mean of those f-measures, and returns those mean values. These are the P, R, and F values you report above.

It is helpful to calculate the precision, recall, and f-measure values for a single item in your list. To calculate the P, R, and F values for the third item in your list, you can run:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

predict = np.array([[1,1,1,1]])
expect = np.array([[1,0,0,0]])
smp_report = metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support(expect, predict, beta=1, average = 'samples')
f_report = metrics.f1_score(expect, predict, average = 'samples')

print f_report, smp_report
```

Running this code gives you `0.4 (0.25, 1.0, 0.40000000000000002)`. The values inside the parenthetical indicate the precision, recall, and f-measure for the classification (in that order). As you can see, the f-measure *is* the harmonic mean between precision and recall:

```
2 * [(.25 * 1) / (.25 + 1) ] = .4
```

By swapping your first two lists into the code above, you can calculate the precision, recall, and harmonic f-measures for each of the three items in your data set:

first item values:

`0.666666666667 (1.0, 0.5, 0.66666666666666663)`

second item values

`0.4 (0.5, 0.33333333333333331, 0.40000000000000002)`

third item values

`0.4 (0.25, 1.0, 0.40000000000000002)`

SK then calculates the mean precision among these precision values, i.e:
 `1 + .5 + .25 / 3 = .5833333333333333)`, the mean recall among these recall values,`(.5 + .333 + 1 / 3 = 0.61111111111111105)`, and the mean f-measure among these f-measures `(.666 + .4 + .4 / 3 = 0.48888888888888893)`, and returns those mean values. These are the values you report above. SK is calculating the harmonic mean for each classification event--it's simply returning the mean of those harmonic means.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, what I am wondering is that why is the f-score NOT equal to the harmonic mean of precision and recall, which is 2*0.58*0.61/(0.58+0.61) = 0.59? Isn't f-score computed in this way? Does it vary in multi-labeal case?

Comment: The F-score *is* equivalent to the harmonic mean of the mean precision and mean recall values across the three items in your set. SK calculates the precision of each classification event and gets .666, .5, and .25. It then takes the mean of those and gets .583333 (this is the precision value you're seeing.) It then calculates the recall value of each classification exercise (.5, .333, .4) and takes their average (=.611). Then it takes the harmonic f measure for each classification instance (.666, .4, .4), and takes their mean (.488).

Comment: In other words, for each classification event, SK calculates the precision and recall, then calculates their harmonic mean. Then, after calculating each of these values for each classification event, SK calculates the means of those values (ie the mean precision value across classification events, the mean recall across classification events, and the mean f-measure across classification events), and returns those mean values in the output you post above. Does that clarify things?

Comment: If you run the code I posted above, for instance, you'll see that you get precision, recall, and f-measure values for the given classification event. You'll also see that the f-measure is the harmonic mean of the precision and recall values returned by the function. If you swap in the other two items in your list (ie [1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1]) one by one, you can get the P, R, and F measure for each of those items. Then, if you take the mean across the P values returned, and the mean for R values, and finally the mean for F values, you get the values you post in your question.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, I got it! I computed the averaged precision and recall across three events and took harmonic mean, leading to the wrong answer 0.59. The correct way is to take average of harmonic mean of precision and recall corresponding to each classification event.